# Google Wallet api POSTBACK_ERROR

Tags: wordpress, payment, android-pay

I’m trying to integrate Google Wallet into my website. I’m getting the message as below. Does anybody know why this happens? What should I do to resolve this issue? Please help me.

> Uh oh. There was a problem.
>
> We couldn't complete your purchase because of a technical issue.
>
> Details of the problem below: Unfortunately, we could not confirm your
>   purchase with the merchant's server. Your order has been canceled.
>   Please contact the merchant if this problem continues.

Getting Postback_error.

Comment: see the logs, post other details..

Answer (score 0):

First, piece of advice that this community reminds everyone when posting questions (or else your question maybe downvoted or closed by the community).

- [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)
- [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

That out of the way, and *assuming* you are referring to Wallet for Digital Goods API, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/postback) should help guide you to debugging your implementation, which seems to point to an error in your POSTBACK handler:

> Important: If you specify a postback URL, your server must respond promptly and correctly to the HTTP POST messages that Google sends for each transaction. Otherwise, the transaction will be canceled.